# Two identical questions - how is it possible?

Tags: support, duplication

I encountered today two exactly identical questions posted at the same time:

[error when setting -genome_size for windowmasker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70332773/error-when-setting-genome-size-for-windowmasker)

[error when setting -genome_size for windowmasker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70332774/error-when-setting-genome-size-for-windowmasker)

I was under the impression that the sites wouldn't even allow that, because already the question *title* would have to be unique, which it isn't.

So I'm concluding that this is likely a bug of sorts. Maybe a race condition in checking if the title exists and creating the new question.